# Origin of divergence in a divergent field (2D)

Tags: calculus, algorithms, numerical-methods, vectors, approximation

I have a field of measured vectors, see example of four vectors in image below. If there was no noise they would all point outward exactly from one "central point". i.e. there would be a circle whose tangent is perpendicular to all vectors. Unfortunately there is some noise in the measurement, I am looking for the best approximation for the center of this circle.

Thanks for your ideas!

[image: Field of measured vectors]

Comment: Hey guys, I clarified my question. Could you please review and see if it is good enough for math exchange? Thanks!

Comment: This is an improvement, but I would like to ask for further clarification.  The vectors appear to have distinct "base points" as well as direction and magnitude.  In some applications the vectors you describe would be called normal vectors (perpendicular to the circle) and the magnitudes would be equal or perhaps unimportant except as to pointing outward from the circle.  Given ideal measurements would this be so?  And do the discrepancies in magnitude give some clue as to which vectors suffer the greatest error/uncertainty?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to minimize the sum of squares of distances from lines determined by the given vectors.

Let's say the vectors are $v_1,\dots,v_n$, positioned at $p_1,\dots,p_n$. Let $u_k$ be a unit vector perpendicular to $v_k$: namely, 
$$
u_k = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix}\frac{v_k}{\|v_k\|^2}
$$
For a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the formula $|(x-p_k)\cdot u_k|$ gives the distance from $x$ to the line determined by the pair $(p_k,v_k)$.

So, the goal is to minimize
$$F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n (x\cdot u_k-p_k\cdot u_k)^2,\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}^2$$
This is easy because $F$ is quadratic in $x$. Its gradient is a linear function of $x$:
$$\nabla F(x) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n (x\cdot u_k-p_k\cdot u_k) u_k $$
The minimizing $x$ is the solution of the linear system $Ax=b$ with 
$$
A = \sum_{k=1}^n (u_k\otimes u_k),\qquad 
b = \sum_{k=1}^n (p_k\cdot u_k) u_k $$
(Using $\otimes$ for [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)).